# Authenticity of Jagannath Ashtakam being a composition of Adi Shankaracharya

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, hymn, jagan-natha

As we know a lot of devotional hymns are misattributed to Shankaracharya with [Jagannath Ashtakam](https://shlokam.org/jagannathashtakam/) being one of them. [Some hymns are verified](https://www.advaita-vedanta.in/questioning-authenticity-of-works-attributed-to-adi-shankara) by the commentaries on them, some by the writing style and others by the message they give (if it is compatible with Advaita). I do know that Sringeri and other matts list it as one of the compositions of Shankara, traditionally. But, I could not find any proof that this ashtakam was actually composed by Adi Shankaracharya. However, I'll be more than happy to be proven wrong. If you have any info regarding this, please share.

Edit-
[One site](https://advocatetanmoy.com/2018/07/14/jagannatha-ashtakam-by-shree-krishna-chaitanya-mahaprabhu/) even says that it was composed by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.